# Is $\pi_0$ of a homotopy cartesian square cartesian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is probably stupid but I don't see an argument.

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
P&\rightarrow & X\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
Y&\rightarrow& Z
\end{eqnarray}
be a homotopy cartesian diagram of simplicial sets. You can assume for example that $X\to Z$ is a Kan fibration and the diagram is cartesian in the categorical sense.

Is
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi_0P&\rightarrow & \pi_0X\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\pi_0Y&\rightarrow& \pi_0Z
\end{eqnarray}
a cartesian diagram of sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true in spaces, certainly: take the homotopy pullback of $* \to S^1 \gets *$, which is $\Omega S^1$. We have that $*$ and $S^1$ are connected, but $\Omega S^1$ is not, since $\pi_0(\Omega S^1) = \pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Now hit everything with the singular complex functor.

Comment: As I feared, it was stupid. Thank you very much. I understand better now what I wanted.